# Как правильно организовать код при оптимизации/разделению таблиц БД

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Имелась таблица Users и к ней одноименная модель

```
id
name
...
facebook
telegram
phone
```

теперь она разделена на две таблицы - все контакты/соцсети вынесены в отдельную UserContacts

```
id
type
contact_name
```

`type` - это тип контакты определенный в модели UserContact как константы.

Модель User связана с UserContact как один-ко-многим. Подобных связей есть еще несколько.
И здесь какраз и вопрос - хотелось бы логику получения/сохранения данных организовать в соответствующих моделях, а не все лепить в модели User (`$this->contacts()->firstWhere('type', UserContact::FACEBOOK)->...`).
Как это все правильно разрулить?

Comment: А зачем вы такую сложную архитектуру лепите? Логично же, что у юзера может быть и фейсбук и телеграм и телефон, так пусть эти данные хранятся вместе. Так же проще и понятнее, чем бесконечно связи всякие делать.

Comment: @ШайтанЯкубович это досталось в наследство. Да и когда в человека 2+ телефонных номера, то лепить их в таблицу юзеров не логично. Тут вопрос в том, что вообще не по феншую логику модели контактов городить в модели пользователей